# Selecting from table is truncating it

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have written code which pulls data from a table and inserts it into a dictionary and then truncates the table and inserts new values in the table however the moment I run the code it immediately truncates the table.

I have tried removing the truncate code however it still truncates the table.

```
import ccxt
import mysql.connector

import os
import sys
import time
from collections import defaultdict
import json 
import requests
import logging
import telegram

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',

host='localhost', database='coinbuys',

auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

mycursor = cnx.cursor()

sql = """SELECT * FROM coinscores """
mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in myresult:
coin_score_symbol = row[1]
coin_score_database_value = row[2]

print (coin_score_symbol)
print (coin_score_database_value)

#this prints nothing ^

sql = "INSERT INTO BUYWALLDATA3 (COINPAIR, price, size, volumethreshold) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
            val = [
                (whichmarket[f], 
var_element_check[0], sum_array_check, volume_threshold)
                ]

            mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

            cnx.commit()

            print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")

for key in coins_with_buy_walls.keys():
sql = """SELECT * FROM BUYWALLDATA3 WHERE COINPAIR = '%s' """ % (key)
rows = 0
mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in myresult:
    rows = rows + 1
    id_table = row[0]
    ticker = row[1]
    coin_price = row[2]
    size_order = row[3]
    volume_calculation = row[4]
    volume_calculation = row[4] + volume_calculation

#Here would be the truncate statement

for a in coin_score:
coin_final_score = coin_score[a]
sql = "INSERT INTO coinscores (symbol, score) VALUES (%s, %s)"              
val = [(a, coin_final_score)]
mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
cnx.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")


# This is the code I used to create the coin scores table 
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE coinscores (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, symbol VARCHAR(255), score VARCHAR(255))")
```

I've included all of my database statements, perhaps there is an issue with them which is causing this. I expect the first database call to print all the values in coin scores and then to wipe it and insert the new data.

Answer (score 0):

I had another file in the folder which had the TRUNCATE line written in and for some reason when I deleted that it fixed the problem.